# java URL cut html code

Tags: java, url

I execute this code from Oracle tutorial,

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();


    }
}
```

but the program doesn't show the complete html code (the response). It seems it hangs.
What's the problem.
I have no proxy.

Comment: how do you know it doesn't show the complete html, there's nothing in the code to tell if it hangs or completes just fine?

Comment: check if you are able to access http://www.oracle.com/ from your machine.

Comment: just put `System.out.println("something");` at end and check if you can see this output

Comment: I tested you code and it seems to work. Are you sure java isn't blocked by a firewall on your computer ?

Comment: I have changed the URL and works.